# Run-time Error '1004'-- AutoFilter Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am pulling a work organization report and want to find and filter by a unique ID value. The unique ID to be filtered is specified by a public property (this number is used on another occasion so that is why it is public) entered through a text box within a userform. The file being used is a dynamically named report that the user selects from an open file dialog.

- User enters unique ID of manager they want to filter under
- Use unique ID to find which manager level column has unique ID
- Move onto the next column if ID is not found
- Once ID is found, Filter column

There are 9 different manager levels I am filtering through, columns AU, AW, AY, BA ,BC, BE, BG, BI, & BK, and they all rest on row 3. Therefore I have columns 'A3:BK3' but am only filtering between 'AU3:BK3' to pull data in the earlier columns.

Problem: I am continuing to receive a "Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed" and I have no idea why, even after trying to debug. It works on some columns, but not on others when using test IDs that are throughout the 9 columns.

Code:

```
Private Sub EmailButton_Click()

    'test WWIDS
    '75305 -- 337431 -- 152820578 -- 152821156

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Filter by WWID -- Question: How to know who to pull for?
'Filter criteria (Unique ID - WWID), if it does not exist, then move to next, else end/stop

    If Len(Trim(Me.EnterWWIDtxtbox.Text)) = 0 Then

        Me.EnterWWIDtxtbox.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Must provide a Unique ID"

        Exit Sub
    End If

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=OpenFileTxt)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 Dim aColumns() As String
    aColumns = Split("AU,AW,AY,BA,BC,BE,BG,BK,BI", ",")

    Dim bFound As Boolean
    bFound = False

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim vColumn As Variant
    For Each vColumn In aColumns
        Set rFound = ws.Columns(vColumn).Find(WWID, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            bFound = True
            MsgBox "Found [" & WWID & "] in column " & vColumn
            With ws.Columns(vColumn)

                .AutoFilter 1, rFound.Value

            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next vColumn

    If bFound = False Then MsgBox "Unique ID [" & WWID & "] not found"

End With
```

Comment: File to the test environment: https://easyupload.io/1p2yoi

Comment: I see a lot of repeating code, I would make a sub with arguments to trim things down a lot.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers -- There is, I copy and pasted the full functionality of the Sub to explain the process. If I was calling subs you would have no idea what was going on. Thanks

Comment: In fact, having tons of repeating code makes it harder to follow. Using subs for repeating code makes it easier to follow.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers sure I can see that and had this in mind, should have just placed on in there and put "...." for the rest .. the below answer you have does not work due to WWIDs varying in nature.. maybe with this in mind it will help.. I will see how the code behaves in my environment and I may be able to tweak it. i appreciate your time.

Comment: i will have another post if I cannot get the second filter to filter parallel -- will DM you so you can practice.

Comment: Look forward to challenges, I have some spare time in the winter to learn and Tackle challenges. FYI, the code in your most current update is more of a minimal verifiable reproducible example than your original code. Try to trim out everything but the problem when posting a question and to be honest I've solved my post while writing the question by trimming the code many a times.

Comment: Sure thing, I will keep note of that. I work in Python so I am not sure what the workflow is like in solving problems in VB-- I guess i should have assumed to keep it the same. Noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to VBA just FYI, I tackle problems to learn, but my answer may not be perfect.

TLDR:

Use: `With ws.Range(rFound.Address(False, False))` NOT `With ws.Columns(vColumn)`

You have a bunch of repeating code which I tried to trim down, but as I'm not 100% on the end goal or how things work, I could only do so much. Here is what I ended up with.

```
Private Sub EmailButton_Click()

'Get WWID
WWID = "111"
'WWID = "777" ' HardCode for Testing

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Dim aColumns() As String
    aColumns = Split("AU,AW,AY,BA,BC,BE,BG,BI,BK", ",")

 If WWID = "111" Then
    Col = "47" 'AU = "47"
 End If
    AW = "49"
    AY = "51"
    BA = "53"
    BC = "55"
    BE = "57"
 If WWID = "777" Then
    Col = "59" 'BG = "59"
 End If
    BI = "61"
    BK = "63"

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim rFound As Range
Dim vColumn As Variant
  For Each vColumn In aColumns
        Set rFound = ws.Columns(vColumn).Find(WWID, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

            With ws.Range(rFound.Address(False, False))

                .AutoFilter Col, rFound.Value

            End With
        End If
    Next vColumn
End Sub
```

Comment: Ideally this would work, I should have also stated that the IDs are varying and not all are the same.. it was just easier creating repetitive input values for each column than randomizing

Comment: It did not.. I am going am preparing a better test file than just the same ID all the way down. This was a confusing way of introducing the problem I am having as your line " If WWID = "111" Then" will not work as the ID's will not be continuous as they are varying.

Comment: Awesome. please accept so others know it's resolved. If your looking to trim down code and run into an issue, that can be a separate thread, but sounds like the "Range Error" is resolved

Comment: I will accept the answer.. but for anyone whom is reading-- my original code just needed tweaking. Thanks for your assistance @FreeSoftwareServers